# Javascript in forms generated by ModelForm

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm using `ModelForm` to generate forms and to make them look good i use `crispyforms`
My question is how can i include javascript event handlers in forms since html code is generated by django.
I am using `ModelForm` and `crispyforms` because i don't know css and html as much as required to make them as much attractive as they are now with these tools?
Or how can i use `crispy forms` with HTML generated forms in case i write myself all the forms in HTML? I am a newbie. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: peoples are answering my question and someone gives me negative * ! Please come forward and edify me about the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `id` of form and fields in browser inspector and add event hendler on this `id`
Or you can render form by each field, like this:

```
<form action="">
    {{ form.some_field }}
    {{ form.other_field }}
<form>
```

and put `{{ form }}` tags in html tag, which you want, like this:
`<p class="some-class"> {{ form.some_field }} </p>`

By crispy forms you can use `FormHelper`, and add classes in `forms.py` file:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    test_field = forms.CharField()

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
                    Field('test_field', css_class="write_class_here")
                    )
```

If you use `FormHelper`, register all fields, like in example and load it in template like this `{% crispy form %}`
here is documentation http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

For django your javascript is static files. See the [Django HOWTO on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to get ideo of how it works.

Shortly you write your `js` file with attached eventListeners and load it with `scripts` tag within your template.